# Drupal 7 Bootstrap .active css can't override?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have an issue to override the bootstrap css for .active.
I have managed to override many others but not this one. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

What I want to do is to change color and bg-color.

Here is my CSS:

```
.active {
  color: #AAAA33;
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

Comment: use `color: #AAAA33 !important;` and `background-color: #303030 !important;` Hope this will fix your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about include "!important" to your code? like

```
color: #AAAA33 !important;
background-color: #303030 !important;
```

If still not work write down all the line in your own css file

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
   color: #AAAA33;
   background-color: #303030;
}
```

Comment: Why duplicate an answer to only add minor adjustment which won't work anyway?

Comment: It might work in some cases but wouldn't be interpreted in the same way in every browsers. Easily breakable IMO.

Comment: "It might work in some case" and "won't work anyway" is different; and this work with me everytime till now, still not see any problem yet but thank for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

To override this kind of elements, you should declare them as `!important`:

```
.active {
    color: #AAAA33 !important;
    background-color: #303030 !important;
}
```

Even if the use of this `!important` is fairly relevant here, considering the *frameworks*, you should be careful about this and don't take the bad habit to use it *everywhere*, like suggested in the article [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) by Chris Coyier.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with !important but the best way was '.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
   color: #AAAA33;
   background-color: #303030;
}'